# WeatherAPP in Swift storyboard

Tags: swift, swiftui, swift4

first of all sorry for my bad english but i'm german, currently i am doing a german tutorial about swift on udemy, unfortunately i can't get any further ...

In the video he shows how to go to Info.plist and then enter the following:

```
<key> NSAppTransportSecurity </key>
          <dict>
            <key> NSExceptionDomains </key>
            <dict>
<key> openweathermap.org </key> <dict>
                  <key> NSIncludesSubdomains </key>
                  <true />
       <key> NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads </
       key>
                  <true />
               </dict>
            </dict>
          </dict>
```

he wrote: We need, because the free version of openWeatherMap is only http and not https. For security reasons, Apple only allows https.

I did everything as in the video but it doesn't work for me ...
Swift just shows me: unable to read the property list. but in the video everything works ...

completed code of properties:

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>CFBundleDevelopmentRegion</key>
    <string>$(DEVELOPMENT_LANGUAGE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleExecutable</key>
    <string>$(EXECUTABLE_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundleIdentifier</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER)</string>
    <key>CFBundleInfoDictionaryVersion</key>
    <string>6.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleName</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_NAME)</string>
    <key>CFBundlePackageType</key>
    <string>$(PRODUCT_BUNDLE_PACKAGE_TYPE)</string>
    <key>CFBundleShortVersionString</key>
    <string>1.0</string>
    <key>CFBundleVersion</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>LSRequiresIPhoneOS</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIApplicationSceneManifest</key>
    <dict>
        <key>UIApplicationSupportsMultipleScenes</key>
        <false/>
        <key>UISceneConfigurations</key>
        <dict>
            <key>UIWindowSceneSessionRoleApplication</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>UISceneConfigurationName</key>
                    <string>Default Configuration</string>
                    <key>UISceneDelegateClassName</key>
                    <string>$(PRODUCT_MODULE_NAME).SceneDelegate</string>
                    <key>UISceneStoryboardFile</key>
                    <string>Main</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </dict>
    <key>UIApplicationSupportsIndirectInputEvents</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UILaunchStoryboardName</key>
    <string>LaunchScreen</string>
    <key>UIMainStoryboardFile</key>
    <string>Main</string>
    <key>UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities</key>
    <array>
        <string>armv7</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
    </array>
    <key>UISupportedInterfaceOrientations~ipad</key>
    <array>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortrait</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft</string>
        <string>UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeRight</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIStatusBarHidden</key>
    <true/>
    <key>UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance</key>
    <false/>
    <key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
           <dict>
             <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
             <dict>
  <key>openweathermap.org</key> <dict>
                   <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                   <true/>
        <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</
        key>
                   <true/>
                </dict>
             </dict>
           </dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Comment: Just fix the key part at the end of the NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads :) you can use an online xml validator as well :). Should be  </key>

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately I don't understand what you mean ... could you write it in a little more detail or even complete the code? this is my first time in the info source code so I don't really understand much there, I just got a guideline from the video how it should be done

Comment: Is that exactly how your Info.plist looks or has the format changed when you added it to the question?

Comment: yea @JoakimDanielson its exactly this

Comment: this line should be like this <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>